# Two methods replacing each other (window.onload/Canvas JS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I haven't been working with javascript before, so I am still learning the basics.

I have included two javascript files in my main file called index.html. The reason for this is to let users select which javascript file to show (**diagram 1** or **diagram 2**) by clicking on the navigation tool bar. The problem is that both of these javascript files have a equal method called **window.onload**, so they replace each other. How can I prevent these two javasript files to replace each other?

First javascript file:

```
window.onload = function {// Preview diagram 1}
```

Second javascript file:

```
window.onload = function {// Preview diagram 2}
```

Here is a snip of what I have in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/diagram1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/diagram2.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery to bind onload event to let both handlers to be fired: `$(window).on('load', function() {...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your both diagram1.js & diagram2.js files, use:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
       // your init code
});
```

to do stuff on window load instead of registering function to `window.onload`.

Comment: This is so because, `window.onload` is kind of a global object, so when you are registering it in your diagram2.js file, it is getting overwritten.